# Library called QtMeL couldn't include the headers

Tags: qt

I'm trying to use a library called [QtMel](http://kibsoft.ru/).

I've done all what it says , I downloaded [Libav](http://libav.org/), [QtMultimediaKit](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21900) and [QtMel](http://kibsoft.ru/)  and put them in a file , every one is in it's own file , then I downloaded opencv and installed it normally

Then tried to do this in my project's pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\\Encoding\\QtMel_Library\\include
LIBS += C:\\Encoding\\QtMel_Library\\lib

CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -lqtmeld1
} else {
    LIBS += -lqtmel1
}
```

and when I tried to include the Recorder header , when I write Rec only it shows that there's a header called recorder but when I include it and then compile my program it says:

```
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Recorder': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error statement is clear! It can not find the file! Did you check you downloaded files ?